# SQL inner join problem

Tags: sql, inner-join

The following SQL query isn't working. I think the error is on the first line.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(tbl_news.comment, 1, 250) as tbl_news.comment, 
    tbl_news.id, tbl_news.date, tbl_news.subject, tbl_users.username 
FROM 
     tbl_news
INNER JOIN 
     tbl_users ON tbl_news.creator = tbl_users.id
ORDER BY 
     date DESC
```

Comment: "Isn't working". What is the error? What isn't working? What is it supposed to do that it isn't?

Comment: *[this] isn't working* doesn't help.  We need to know the error and/or what you expect to be getting.  With DB queries it's even harder because we may also need to know schema.

Comment: Sorry, it was the tbl_news.comment that isnt allowed. Thanks

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so: what version? If not: what database system is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(tbl_news.comment, 1, 250) as comment, 
        tbl_news.id, tbl_news.date, tbl_news.subject, tbl_users.username 
FROM tbl_news
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_news.creator = tbl_users.id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your alias  `as tbl_news.comment` is allowed to have a dot in it.   What error are you getting?  What flavor of SQL is it?  Thanks.

Comment: Mixture of both Lester -- you're probably right about the alias but the questions should be comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(tbl_news.comment, 1, 250) as comment, 
        tbl_news.id, tbl_news.date, tbl_news.subject, tbl_users.username FROM tbl_news
        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_news.creator = tbl_users.id
        ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(tn.comment, 1, 250) AS "tbl_news.comment", 
         tn.id, 
         tn.date, 
         tn.subject, 
         tu.username 
    FROM tbl_news tn
    JOIN tbl_users tu ON tu.id = tn.creator
ORDER BY tn.date DESC
```

Using single quotes on the column alias also worked for me on SQL Server:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(tn.comment, 1, 250) AS 'tbl_news.comment', 
         tn.id, 
         tn.date, 
         tn.subject, 
         tu.username 
    FROM tbl_news tn
    JOIN tbl_users tu ON tu.id = tn.creator
ORDER BY tn.date DESC
```

Comment: +1 interesting - didn't know you could create dotted aliases for columns... you learn something *every* day ! :-)

Comment: @marc_s: Did it with backticks in MySQL recently, but I certainly don't recommend the practice.  I'd buy the following for any co-irkers who do: http://www.despair.com/mis24x30prin.html